# How do I return an error within match statement while implementing from_str in rust?

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust.
I'm trying to follow the example for implementing the from_str trait here

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html

But I keep getting this error pointing at 'return Err(Self::Err)'

```
variant or associated item not found in `black_jack_tools::PlayerDifficulty`
```

I have an idea of why, Self::Err isn't defined in my enum But I don't get why rust cares in this scenario since I'm returning an Err of my Err object which is inline with the Result<Self,Self::Err> type.

Here's my FromStr is below here's a link to the [rust playground with an MRE](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=51426b652f667f921f44ca3a459be4bb)

```
impl FromStr for PlayerDifficulty {
    type Err = ParseError;
    fn from_str(s:&str) -> Result<Self,Self::Err>{
        let result = match s {
            "Player" => Ok(PlayerDifficulty::Player),
            "Dealer" => Ok(PlayerDifficulty::Dealer),
            "Normal" => Ok(PlayerDifficulty::Normal),
            "Perfect"=> Ok(PlayerDifficulty::Perfect),
            "Micky" =>  Ok(PlayerDifficulty::Micky),
            "Elliot" => Ok(PlayerDifficulty::Elliot),
            "Cultist"=> Ok(PlayerDifficulty::Cultist),
            _ => return Err(Self::Err)
        };
    }
}
```

What Am I doing wrong?
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Function will return it last statement. Remove the last semicolon, and you could also remove the internal return statement.

Comment: Your error disappears if you write `return Err (<Self as FromStr>::Err)` instead of `return Err (Self::Err)`. However this may cause other problems depending on where your `ParseError` comes from, but since you didn't provide a [mre] it's hard to anticipate what these problems may be (in particular `std::string::ParseError` can never be instantiated so the code can't work if this is the `PareError` you mean).

Comment: @jmb I've added an MRE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three issues with your code. The first is that you need to use `<Self as FromStr>::Err` if you want to refer to the `Err` type in your `FromStr` implementation:

```
impl FromStr for PlayerDifficulty {
    type Err = ParseError;
    fn from_str(s:&str) -> Result<Self,Self::Err>{
        let result = match s {
            "Player" => Ok(PlayerDifficulty::Player),
            /* ... */
            _ => return Err(<Self as FromStr>::Err)
        };
    }
}
```

`Self::Err` tries to look for an `Err` variant in the `PlayerDifficulty` enum but there is no such variant.

The second issue is that [`std::string::ParseError`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/type.ParseError.html) is in fact an alias for [`std::convert::Infallible`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/enum.Infallible.html), which is an error that can never happen and cannot be instantiated. Since your conversion may fail, you need to use an error that can be instantiated or define your own:

```
struct UnknownDifficultyError;
impl FromStr for PlayerDifficulty {
    type Err = UnknownDifficultyError;
    fn from_str(s:&str) -> Result<Self,Self::Err>{
        let result = match s {
            "Player" => Ok(PlayerDifficulty::Player),
            /* ... */
            _ => return Err(UnknownDifficultyError),
        };
    }
}
```

Finally, you need to return the result even when conversion succeeds, by removing the `let result =`  and the semicolon:

```
struct UnknownDifficultyError;
impl FromStr for PlayerDifficulty {
    type Err = UnknownDifficultyError;
    fn from_str(s:&str) -> Result<Self,Self::Err>{
        match s {
            "Player" => Ok(PlayerDifficulty::Player),
            /* ... */
            _ => return Err(UnknownDifficultyError),
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=240f689c7913ead27be431592cc56332)

Comment: Thanks man. I don't get  whats happening here though '<Self as FromStr>::Err'  coming from other languages 'as' looks like a cast? is it casting my player difficulty object into a trait? How does this work in rust?

Comment: Here `Self` is both the `PlayerDifficulty` enum and "something that implements `FromStr`". When you write `Self::Foo`, the compiler needs to know whether it must look for `Foo` in the `PlayerDifficulty` enum or in the `FromStr` trait (especially since there may be something called `Foo` in both). By default it looks in the enum itself, the `<Self as FromStr>` syntax tells it to look in the `FromStr` implementation instead.

Answer (score 1):

The function will return it last statement. Remove the last semicolon, and you could also remove the internal return statement, the result of the `match` statement will be returned.

Is there a better way? It looks like you are parsing a string to a `enum`, the create [enum-utils](https://crates.io/crates/enum-utils) does that. Instead of implementing the parser with boilerplate code you just derive it.

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, enum_utils::FromStr)]
enum PlayerDifficulty {
    Player,
    Dealer,
    Cultist,
    Normal,
}

fn main() {
    let _x:PlayerDifficulty= "Player".parse().unwrap();
}
```

And in your cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
enum-utils = "0.1.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a custom error

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct PlayerError;

impl std::fmt::Display for PlayerError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Could not parse player")
    }
}
impl std::error::Error for PlayerError{}
```

Then change the match always return the `Result` in the same path

```
use std::str::FromStr;

impl FromStr for PlayerDifficulty {
    type Err = PlayerError;
    fn from_str(s:&str) -> Result<Self,Self::Err>{
        match s {
            "Player" => Ok(PlayerDifficulty::Player),
            "Dealer" => Ok(PlayerDifficulty::Dealer),
            "Normal" => Ok(PlayerDifficulty::Normal),
            "Perfect"=> Ok(PlayerDifficulty::Perfect),
            "Micky" =>  Ok(PlayerDifficulty::Micky),
            "Elliot" => Ok(PlayerDifficulty::Elliot),
            "Cultist"=> Ok(PlayerDifficulty::Cultist),
            _ =>        Err(PlayerError)
        }
    }
}
```

And use it with `?` to propagate error.

```
fn main() -> (Result<(),Box<dyn std::error::Error>>) {
    let _x = PlayerDifficulty::from_str("Player")?;
    let _x = PlayerDifficulty::from_str("PlayerPlayer")?;
    Ok(())
}
```