# How to re-expose an IntoIterator implementation with generics?

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to extend the `VecDeque` type to drop elements after a max capacity. However, I'm getting stuck on implementing `IntoIterator` with the generics and am getting an error I don't understand.

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

struct SlidingQueue<T> {
    data: VecDeque<T>,
    max_capacity: usize,
}

// just re-expose the VecDeque::IntoIter
impl<T> IntoIterator for SlidingQueue<T> {
    type Item = T;

    // type IntoIter=VecDeque<Self::Item>::IntoIter;
    type IntoIter = VecDeque<T>::IntoIter;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.data.into_iter()
    }
}
```

```
error[E0223]: ambiguous associated type
  --> src/lib.rs:13:21
   |
13 |     type IntoIter = VecDeque<T>::IntoIter;
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: use fully-qualified syntax: `<VecDeque<T> as Trait>::IntoIter`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0223`.
```

The  `rustc --explain E0223` explainer seems to indicate I'm referencing an undefined type in a trait... but I don't think that's true.  My attempts to do what the compiler suggests also fail.

How can I express this?

Comment: Try `<VecDeque<T> as IntoIterator>::IntoIter`

Comment: For an explanation, take a look at my comment in reply to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67822027/5397009)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler just tells you that it doesn't know where `VecDeque<T>::IntoIter` comes from.

It can come from the implementation of `IntoIterator` for `VecDeque<T>`, but it can also potentially come from some different trait implementation that also has an associated type named `IntoIter`.

So you need to tell the compile which trait to take the associated type from, using *fully-qualified path*:

```rust
type IntoIter = <VecDeque<T> as IntoIterator>::IntoIter;
```

Or just follow the documentation [that tells us](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#impl-IntoIterator-for-VecDeque%3CT%2C%20A%3E) that this type is named [`std::collections::vec_deque::IntoIter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/vec_deque/struct.IntoIter.html):

```rust
type IntoIter = std::collections::vec_deque::IntoIter<T>;
```

Comment: Thank you!  I swore of the many things I tried, that was one... but must have had some other problem.  Thank you.